# Разница DateTime в С#

Tags: c#, datetime

Подскажите как лучше всего добиться разницы, выраженной в мин. и сек., между 2-мя объектами `DateTime`.

Есть: 2 объекта `DateTime`. Один был запущен в начале работы программы(пускай это будет `dateTime_1`), другой - `dateTime_2` = `DateTime.Now`.

И вот я пытаюсь найти решение как правильно вытянуть из `dateTime_2 - dateTime_1` кол-во минут и секунд.

Пробовал несколько способов:

```
1.
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now - dateTime_1;
var z = timeSpan.Duration();
Console.WriteLine(z.Minutes + " " + z.Seconds);

2.
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dateTime_1);
Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.Minutes + " " + timeSpan.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeSpan` - как раз структура данных для инкапсулирования интервала времени.

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2020, 3, 24, 8, 6, 5);
var dateTime2 = new DateTime(2020, 3, 24, 9, 25, 17);
var timespan = dateTime2 - dateTime;
Console.WriteLine($"Разница: {timespan.Hours}:{timespan.Minutes}:{timespan.Seconds}");
Console.WriteLine($"Всего минут: {timespan.TotalMinutes}");
Console.WriteLine($"Всего секунд: {timespan.TotalSeconds}");
```

Проперти ничинающиеся с Total* покажут нужное значение всего (`TotalMinutes` сколько например всего минут в интервале)

Подробнее про `TimeSpan` можно прочитать тут: [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Я бы переписал, так `Console.WriteLine($"Разница: {timespan.TotalHours}:{timespan.Minutes}:{timespan.Seconds}");`